# Is possible to construct a com.google.common.collect.Table from an existing map?

Tags: java, guava

Suppose I have an existing Map<Integer, Map<Integer, String>> which contains items, I want to construct a com.google.common.collect.Table from that map for there's unnecessary data copy

Comment: https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#newCustomTable-java.util.Map-com.google.common.base.Supplier-

Comment: @shmosel. thanks for reply, the backingMap must be empty according the api :(

Comment: Indeed. Weird that it doesn't mention that till the `@throws` section. And that it accepts a map instance instead of a supplier.